# Calling my class & method from a button in another class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a WindowsForm that has a DataGridView that shows output of my app.  The class with the button is DriveRecursion_Results.cs.  I want it so that once the button is pushed by the user, my method FileCleanUp() in my SanitizeFileNames class is called.  I'm not quite sure how to do this though.

Here is the code for both classes:

```
    public partial class DriveRecursion_Results : Form
{
    public DriveRecursion_Results()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void DriveRecursion(string retPath)
    {
        //recurse through files.  Let user press 'ok' to move onto next step        
        // string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(retPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        string pattern = " *[\\~#%&*{}/<>?|\"-]+ *";
        //string replacement = "";
        Regex regEx = new Regex(pattern);

        string[] fileDrive = Directory.GetFiles(retPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        List<string> filePath = new List<string>();


        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        try
        {
            foreach (string fileNames in fileDrive)
            {

                if (regEx.IsMatch(fileNames))
                {
                    string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileName(fileNames);
                    string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(fileNames);

                    DataGridViewRow dgr = new DataGridViewRow();
                    filePath.Add(fileNames);
                    dgr.CreateCells(dataGridView1);
                    dgr.Cells[0].Value = pathOnly;
                    dgr.Cells[1].Value = fileNameOnly;
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dgr);
                    filePath.Add(fileNames);
                }

                else
                {
                    DataGridViewRow dgr2 = new DataGridViewRow();
                    dgr2.Cells[0].Value = "No Files To Clean Up";
                    dgr2.Cells[1].Value = "";
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(retPath + "ErrorLog.txt");
            sw.Write(e);

        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //i want to call SanitizeFileName's method FileCleanup here.



    }


}
```

Here is SanitizeFileNames:

```
public class SanitizeFileNames
{

    public void FileCleanup(List<string>filePath)
    {
        string regPattern = "*[\\~#%&*{}/<>?|\"-]+*";
        string replacement = "";
        Regex regExPattern = new Regex(regPattern);


        foreach (string files2 in filePath)
        {
            try
            {
                string filenameOnly = Path.GetFileName(files2);
                string pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(files2);
                string sanitizedFileName = regExPattern.Replace(filenameOnly, replacement);
                string sanitized = Path.Combine(pathOnly, sanitizedFileName);
                //write to streamwriter
                System.IO.File.Move(files2, sanitized);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { 
            //write to streamwriter

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   List<string> paths = new List<string>()
   // initialize paths to whatever is neccessary
   //....
   new SanitizeFileNames().FileCleanUp(paths)
}
```

Just create an instance of the class, and call the method.
However, the method itself does not use the state of the class, so it can be changed to a static method

```
public static void FileCleanup(List<string>filePath)
```

and you'll be able to call it without creating an instance, directly from the class, like this:

```
SanitizeFileNames.FileCleanUp(paths)
```

Comment: SWeko has the correct syntax.  Is your SanitizeFileNames in App_Code or in a separate assembly?

Comment: but i need to reference filePath in the DriveRecursion path so that my FileCleanup() method can do a file rename.  how do i refer to filePath from the other class?

Comment: @yeahumok - The caller (button click event) has to pass it in.  How is DriveRecursion called?  Since the click event handler is in the same class, it should have access to the path information as well.

Comment: @yeahumok - In the code you provided, DriveRecursion is never called. If you want DriveRecursion to use the FileCleanUp method, just call it as specified. If you want FileCleanUp to use the result (or a side-effect) of DriveRecursion, either return that value, or set a class-level field to the needed value.

Comment: i'm still very confused.  i don't get what i'm supposed to instantiate in the button or how i link my paths from filePath in the previous class to my button.